# Java FXML Error Loading Anchor Pane

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to run a previously running Java FX application and am getting an error loading the anchor pane. This error is in part of the code that I haven't touched since it was working so I'm not sure what caused it. Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private Composition composition;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    mainWindow();
}

public void mainWindow(){

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindowView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        MainWindowController mainWindowController  = loader.getController();
        mainWindowController.setMain(this);
        mainWindowController.setCompositon(composition);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        mainWindowController.run();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users...bin/application/MainWindowView.fxml:11

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at application.Main.mainWindow(Main.java:27)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162 
  (LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175 
  (PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173 
  (PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174 
  (PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run 
 (InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.MainWindowController.<init>(MainWindowController.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance 
  (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance 
  (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute 
   (FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement 
  (FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 10 more
```

I believe the error is being thrown while loading the AnchorPane, but I'm not completely sure. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [What is NullPointerException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you share the contents of MainWindowView.fxml? Whatever is on line 11 should provide a clue as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Ah, I see - you'll have to look at line 57 in _MainWindowController.java_ to see what is throwing the `NullPointerException`.